# Java connect to Access Database

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc, relational-database

Im trying to be able to access data from an access database.

I have configured the odbc driver for *.mdb and *.accdb files under the ODBC Administrator. I am using windows 7 through parallels(not sure if that makes a difference)

When i run the program I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no     default driver specified
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3080)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at DataAccess.main(DataAccess.java:13)
```

start code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DataAccess 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String connURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+"C:\\Users\\alexmac\\Desktop\\OASDatabase\\OAS_Database";

            String table = "Student";        
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL, "", "");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();

              // Fetch table
        String selTable = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
        s.execute(selTable);
        ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
        while((rs!=null) && (rs.next()))
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " : " + rs.getString(2));
        }

        // close and cleanup
        s.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You might also look into the [jacksess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) library, which also works on all platforms (i.e. not windows-specific). In my opinion, it's also easier to use than the JDBC/ODBC oriented driver.

Comment: No, `Driver={MSAccessDriver ...}` won't work either. Take another look at my answer.

Comment: changed the driver to match your answer i believe. still getting the same error. I downloaded the 32 bit and 64 bit jdk to have both.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));` say?

Comment: 64. so then its 64 bit?

Comment: That's right, it means that your app is running in a 64-bit JVM (Java Virtual Machine). So, do you have Microsoft Office 2007 or later installed on your machine? If so, is it the 32-bit or 64-bit version? If you don't have Office on your machine have you installed the 64-bit version of the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255)?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the double-extension problem (`.accdb.accdb`) mentioned in the comment above, your code won't work because the driver name you specified...

`DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)}`

...is incorrect. There is no ODBC driver with that name. 32-bit applications that want to open an older `.mdb` database file can use

`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}`

To open an `.mdb` file from a 64-bit application, or to open an `.accdb` file from *any* application, you need to use

`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`

Comment: so i took out the String database and changed connURL to      String connURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={MSAccessDriver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+"C:\\Users\\alexmac\\Desktop\\OASDatabase\\OAS_Database.accdb";

Comment: @user214577 It would be easier for all concerned if you were to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19962889/edit) your question with new information.